# Cardinality of computable numbers in range $(0, 1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm reading a book called Turing's vision. It claims that the cardinality of computable numbers in range $(0, 1)$ is the same as the cardinality of the cardinality of computable numbers. Is there a way to prove that?

The book does prove that the cardinality of computable numbers is the same as that of natural numbers and rational numbers, meaning it's countable.

It also uses a smooth tangent function to prove that the cardinality of all real numbers in the range $(0, 1)$ is the same as that of all real numbers. But I don't see that translating over to computable numbers using a tangent.

Comment: If the set of all computable numbers is countable, then the set of those in the unit interval is at most countable. But it's not finite, since e.g. $1/n$ is computable for $n=1,2,3,....$, so it must be countably infinite. (I don't recall the definition of computable number, but I'm guessing that it includes $1/n$ for all such $n$.)

Comment: More modern definitions of computable numbers include rationals basically by definition. But informal definitions often involve something like: "there is a Turing machine that can compute the decimal expansion of the number". So numbers like $\frac{1}{10^n}$ are very easy to see under this latter definition.

Comment: halrankard: In his paper, Turing supposedly allowed the Turing machine to compute irrational numbers by allowing expansion, meaning given any n, the machine can calculate the number to n decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple ways to answer this.

The simplest is to observe that every rational number is computable. Since there are infinitely many rational numbers in $(0,1)$, that means that there are infinitely many computable numbers in $(0,1)$, so the cardinality of the set of computable numbers in $(0,1)$ is at least $\aleph_0$. Since you already know that it's at most $\aleph_0$, this gives the answer.

More satisfyingly, we can whip up an explicit bijection between the set $X$ of computable numbers in $(0,1)$ and the set $Y$ of all computable numbers. Specifically, we're interested in functions which **send computable numbers to computable numbers**. The key fact is the following:

> Suppose that $f$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is computable whenever $x$ is, and $f^{-1}(x)$ is computable whenever $x$ is. Then $f\upharpoonright X$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$.

With this in hand, all we need to do is show that your favorite bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is "computability-preserving in both directions" - which is a bit tedious, but not hard. In particular, the map $$x\mapsto \tan(\pi x-{\pi\over 2})$$ has this property.

Comment: "computability-preserving in both directions" - which is a bit tedious, but not hard. That's basically what I was stuck on. The book uses the exact function for bijection from unit interval to R. Can you outline the steps for this bit? Thank.s